# Excel bug tracking + link to code line?

Tags: vb.net, vb6, bug-tracking

I'm a small developer in VB6 and VB.net, and use for bugtracking a simple Excel. Seemed to me that I didnt need anything more.

I've wanted to add links to the code. Then:

- How can I do it for vb6 and for vs.net?
- Is this reasonable? Should I change to a (free) bugtracking tool? Do they have this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a list of bug-trackers [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328/what-bug-tracking-software-do-you-use).

Do you want to link source code changes to particular bug fixes? That means integrating your bug-tracker with your version-control / revision-control system. (You do have version control, right? It's **essential**.) You could check the Wikipedia bug-tracker [comparison table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_issue_tracking_systems) looking at the revision control integration column.

[FogBugz](http://www.fogcreek.com/fogbugz) is [popular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328/what-bug-tracking-software-do-you-use/12346#12346) on StackOverflow, I hear it does integrate with version control, and it is free for one-person companies. Disclaimer: it was developed by [a founder of Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4/joel-spolsky), so that may bias StackOverflow users in its favour slightly.